# ember - load model from ajax is undefinded

Tags: javascript, ajax, ember.js, model

Well, I need to load my model after ajax request complete.

When the ajax request is complete I push the data into store. After pushing I need to return the data and render it on the template. Problem is, the `{{model}}` variable is empty.

```
model(params) {
    const controller = this.controllerFor('users.profile');

    return controller.get('session').authorize('authorizer:devise', (headerName, headerValue) => {
        const url = '/api/users/profile/'+this.get('session.data.authenticated.user.id');

        return Ember.$.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: controller.get('backendURL')+url,
            dataType: 'json',
            //data: ,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            beforeSend:  function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader(headerName, headerValue);
            },
            success: function(
                this.store.pushPayload('user',data);
                //at this point I can see the user info in the ember inspector addon.
                return Ember.RSVP.resolve(data);//return usr;
            },
            error: function(data){
                controller.get('flashMessages').danger('ERROR, '+ data);
                Ember.$("#loading").hide("slow");
                controller.set('seeTable',false);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Any suggestions, whats is wrong on my route?

Comment: should it be `success: function(data) { .... }`?

Comment: I think you should not mix authorization and getting the model in one model hook. My advise would be: use Ember Simple Auth for authorization!

Answer (score 0):

`$.ajax` does not return promise object, to make it compatible with Ember `model()` function you should wrap it with Promise object:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  $.ajax({
    success() {
      ....
      resolve(data);
    }
  }) 
})
```

Anyway, I don't recommend you to use `$.ajax`, and load data using Ember models.